# django user management adding user with ajax

Tags: ajax, django, cross-domain

In django library, there is a user management where it allows adding of users to the database. I have a web page that allows creation of user, but what I want to do is to be able to create users remotely from another domain, by posting the username password etc over ajax to django.

in urls.py:

```
url(r'^user/add/$', UserCreateView.as_view(), name='user_add'),
```

views.py:

```
class UserCreateView(SingleObjectCreateView):
    user = UserForm
    view_permission = permission_user_create

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.set_unusable_password()
        user.save()
        messages.success( self.request, _('User "$s" created successfully.') % user )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(
            reverse('user_management:user_set_password', args=(user.pk,))
        )
```

my ajax post from the other domain:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "https://mydjangourl/accounts/user/add/",
  data: {
    username: "testusername",
    first_name: "firstname",
    last_name: "lastname",
    is_active: "on",
    submit: ""
  }
});
```

When I created a user from my django app, I compared the form data being posted with my personal JavaScript app, both posted the same form data over, but when I checked the database no new user was being created from my personal app.. Am I posting it wrongly?

Note: csrftoken authentication has been disabled as it is not required. We are running in an offline environment.

Comment: If you can give more information about **UserForm** then I will be able to help you further. Please share the import /other details.

Comment: have you checked this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35377334/how-do-i-create-a-new-user-using-ajax-with-jsonresponse-in-django

Comment: the codes jumps from one file to the other, and since I'm working offline I'm unable to just copy and paste everything. I'm working on Mayan EDMS: https://www.mayan-edms.com  , this has a user_management app. The reason I did not follow the link Midhun Mohan shown was because I'm new to python and django, and there seems to be some relationship between different tables rather than just a simple user table, so I thought it would be easier to simply use existing APIs available.

Comment: Is this the real code? Can't see any SingleObjectCreateView with a user as parameter in the doc.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link:-
[CreateView with AJAX Mixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#ajax-example)

I suppose, this should solve your problem :-)